# c# OPEN XML word - Table of contents emessage on load

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, tableofcontents

I am creating Table of Contents in MS Word from C# using `OPEN XML SDK Framework`. After creating the docx every time I am opening the document it is showing me the message `This document contains fields that may refer to other files. Do you want to update the fields in this document ?`.
I do not want the user to see this message every time they open the doc . Is there any alternate of achieving the same without warning message without going through the path of unchecking the word settings.

Comment: The reason for this is a security measure. The only way to avoid the message is to open the document using Word Automation Services in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you can amend the normal.dotx template then yes this is possible.  Eric White has a [video here that describes this in much more detail](https://youtu.be/GtVB3VKdUqk) and a whole library of code to do with table of contents.  Watch that video for the complete guide on how to do it, but the key parts are:

1. Don't set the element to be dirty, remove the blue bit in the screen grab below:
   [image]
2. Don't update the TOC fields from code
3. Add an `AutoOpen` macro in the normal.dotx template and then add this code to that:
   [image]